# Will enabling proprietary drivers on 17.04 install affect secureboot and bitlocker partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, windows-10, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I have a Windows 10 Bitlocker partition that if I understand correctly requires SecureBoot to be enabled.

The BIOS in my Asus Z170-A motherboard does not give me the option to disable this, so I cannot test if it will boot without it.

I have attempted to install Ubuntu 17.04 alongside windows and the installer froze with `nouveau sched_error` messages presumably because of my graphics card, a 1080 Ti.

By adding `nomodeset` to the boot options I was able to get the disk to install. I did not select "install proprietary drivers" because the prompt warned that it would disable secure boot, which I feared would permanently prevent me from booting into Windows 10.

The install was successful, but presented me with a purple screen on launch, until I again added `nomodeset` to the boot options.

I was able to log in, and the system worked fine, but at low resolution with massive screen tearing.

I ended up deleting the partition, and want to try again from scratch.

If I enable the proprietary drivers, will it effect my ability to boot into a bitlocker encrypted drive?

Will it fix my graphical issues?

Comment: Now this is a very good question, albeit off-topic because its core is all about Windows and Windows only. That said, there are discussions about it in the usual places like this one https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ddc89857-eae4-4678-bb24-b5eb2e68f136/secure-boot-and-bitlocker-on-win10?forum=win10itprosecurity

Comment: This was totally  relevant for Ubuntu. EVERYTHING in the actual question dealt with Ubuntu - Windows Secure Boot was merely context. This was bad work by the mods.